# How to show uniqueness of ANF using Lagrange interpolation method?

Tags: boolean-algebra, cryptography, lagrange-interpolation

Given ANF (Algebraic Normal Form) as following:

$$f(x) = \oplus_{I \in P(N)} a_I (\sqcap_{i \in I} x_i) = \oplus_{I \in P(N)} a_I x^I$$..

The definition is taken from [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7214/73172bacf0bdc2efee86314b07e60f1c1110.pdf) and from the same source he says that to prove uniqueness we use Lagrange's interpolation. Can someone explain how this works.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author already gave the algorithm (here he uses "Lagrange interpolation") that every Boolean function $f:\{0,1\}^n \to \{0,1\}$ has at least one ANF, that is what the adding of the elementary functions is (the worked out example on page 9/10).

This then shows that the map that sends $f$ to the polynomial ANF, is wll-defined and being onto is clear (as an ANF clearly defines a Boolean fucntion) (and it's clearly linear too). 
Then it is stated that the set of all ANF-like functions (the polynomial space quotient) has the same dimension as $\mathcal{BF}_n$, so linear algebra (not Lagrange) tells us the unicity, not Lagrange.